# Tempo de atividade do chat é incorreto

Tags: bug, status-intencional, chat

Os locais que mostram há quanto tempo atrás foi enviada a última mensagem no chat praticamente nunca mostram o tempo correto:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olha eu ali eheh :P

Comment: Tenho 99% de certeza de que é cache e será corrigido no dia de São Nunca.

Comment: @bfavaretto A gente dá diversos nomes pras coisas aqui na SE, e isso já é 50% dos [problemas difíceis](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) da computação. Está de bom tamanho...